# PySimpleGui is not able to find modules listed in the python script

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

I have an interface created by PySimpleGui, that allows the user t0:

- set some arguments for the tests
- browse to the folder containing all the tests
- launch the command to run the python script along with all the arguments

In the current state, the interface can set the arguments, select the test folder, and send the command. However when the python script runs the modules included in the script are not loaded. It searches for the modules in the venv of the gui code and not in the venv of the folder that contains the test scripts.

```
import sys
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import infraLib
import glob
from serial.tools.list_ports import comports
import os
import subprocess
import pytest

infraData = infraLib.infraCommands()

def window_layout(ttTTY, vlbTTY):

    layout_01 = [
        [sg.Text('Choose TT port ', size=(30), font=('Arial', 10), justification='left')],
        [sg.Combo(ttTTY, default_value='None', key='_tt_')],
        [sg.Text('Choose VLB port ',  size=(30), font=('Arial', 10), justification='left')],
        [sg.Combo(vlbTTY, default_value='None', key='_vlb_')],
    ]

    layout_02 = [[sg.Text('Browse to Test folder'), sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key='_folder_'), sg.FolderBrowse()]]

    layout_03 = [
        [sg.Checkbox('Default Tests', key=('_0_'), default=False)],
        [sg.Checkbox('User Management Tests', key=('_1_'), default=False)]
    ]

    layout_04 = [
        [sg.Button("Run"), sg.Button('Exit'), sg.Button('Cancel')]
    ]

    layout = [
        [sg.T('Run tests on-demand', font='_ 14', justification='c', expand_x=True)],
        [sg.T("      ")],
        [sg.Col(layout_01, p=0, justification="left", size=(300,150))],
        [sg.Col(layout_02, p=0, justification='left')],
        [sg.Col(layout_03, p=0, justification='left')],
        [sg.Output(size=(80, 20))],
        [sg.Col(layout_04, p=0, justification='c')]
    ]
    return layout

def run_cmd(folderPath, test_cmd, tty_tt_vlb):
    os.chdir(os.path.normpath(folderPath))
    print(os.getcwd())
    tPath = os.path.normpath(folderPath)
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        tty_tt = tty_tt_vlb[0].strip('COM')
        tty_vlb = tty_tt_vlb[1].strip('COM')
        pCall = "python"
    if sys.platform == "linux":
        tty_tt = tty_tt_vlb[0]
        tty_vlb = tty_tt_vlb[1]
        pCall = "python3"

    match (test_cmd):
        case "default":
            mFlag = '"default"'
            cmdStr = pCall + ' -m pytest -vvv --tty ' + tty_tt + ',' + tty_vlb + ' -m=' + mFlag + ' ' + tPath + ' ' + optArg
        # case "factory reset":
        #     mFlag = "factory"
        case "userMgmt":
            optArg = "UserManagement"
            cmdStr = pCall + ' -m pytest -vvv --tty ' + tty_tt + ',' + tty_vlb + ' ' + tPath + ' ' + optArg

    #cmdStr = pCall + ' -m pytest -vvv --tty ' + tty_tt + ',' + tty_vlb + ' -m=' + mFlag + ' ' + tPath + ' ' + optArg
    print(cmdStr)
    sp = subprocess.Popen(cmdStr, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=None)
    out, err = sp.communicate()
    if out:
        print(out.decode("utf-8"))
    if err:
        print(err.decode("utf-8"))


ports_list = list(comports())
TTYs = []
for port in ports_list:
    TTYs.append(port.name)

temp_vlb_ports = infraData.get_vlb_ports(TTYs)
temp_tt_ports = infraData.get_tt_ports(TTYs, temp_vlb_ports)

tty_vlb_ports = []
tty_tt_ports = []

for tport in TTYs:
    for vKey, vValue in temp_vlb_ports.items():
        if vKey == tport:
            tty_vlb_ports.append(tport)
    for tKey, tValue in temp_tt_ports.items():
        if tKey == tport:
            tty_tt_ports.append(tport)


wlayout = window_layout(tty_tt_ports, tty_vlb_ports)
window = sg.Window("Run tests on-demand", wlayout, default_element_size=(25, 1), auto_size_text=False, finalize=True)


while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    # End program if user closes window or presses the Exit or Cancel button
    if event == 'Exit' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':
        break
    elif values is None:
        break
    elif event == '_folder_':
        folder = values['_folder_']
        # os.chdir(values[folder])
    elif event == 'Run':
        justChecked = [element for element in values if values[element] == True]
        tt_vlb_port = values['_tt_'], values['_vlb_']
        if ('_0_') in justChecked:
            run_cmd(folder, "default", tt_vlb_port)
        if ('_1_') in justChecked:
            # run_cmd(folder, "factory", tt_vlb_port)
            run_cmd(folder, "userMgmt", tt_vlb_port)

window.close()
```

Any suggestions to get around this?

Thanks,
Archie

Comment: Any short code to demo your question ?

Comment: Added a picture of the gui interface.

Comment: It may depend on the code in your script and the structure of your files and directories, not about the GUI interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is too long and not executable on my platform, so I create a new one and short one, it work.

Note: It call Python to run the `test.py` under the selected folder.

```py
# D:/py/print_hello.py

def print_hello():
    print('Hello World !')
```

```py
# D:/py/test.py

from print_hello import print_hello

print_hello()
```

```py
# D:/Main.py

import os
import subprocess
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def run_cmd(folder):
    os.chdir(os.path.normpath(folder))
    path    = os.path.normpath(folder)
    cmdStr  = f'python {path}/test.py'
    print(cmdStr)
    sp = subprocess.Popen(cmdStr, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=None)
    out, err = sp.communicate()
    if out:
        print(out.decode("utf-8"))
    if err:
        print(err.decode("utf-8"))

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Browse to Test folder'),
     sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key='_folder_'),
     sg.FolderBrowse()],
    [sg.Button("Run")],
    [sg.Output(size=(80, 20))],
]
window = sg.Window("Run tests on-demand", layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Run':
        folder = values['_folder_']
        if folder:
            run_cmd(folder)

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: In your example, the script is running in the same folder. In my case, the pysimplegui script and the tests are in different locations. The gui is used to navigate to the location of the tests and launch them. However, when the tests are launched the modules are not picked from the location of the tests. So all the modules need to be re-installed in the location of the  pysimplegui script.

Comment: In my example, the script can be running in any other folder, actually, the pysimplegui script and the tests are in different locations.

Comment: True, but the script 'print hello world' does not require any special modules that need to be loaded.

Comment: Updated as above.